# HOW TO: Resolve HP Printer Driver Installation Issues on Windows 10

Tags: windows, hp, drivers, usb, printer

## Symptoms

First off; for several HP OfficeJet Printers (such as with the **HP Officejet 6500A e-All-in-One Printer - E710a**) the **HP Installer** downloaded from the website, or via the **HP Print and Scan Doctor**, will **NOT** install the Drivers for a USB Connected Printer. It just isn’t detected.

**NOTE:** You can copy the **HP Print and Scan Doctor** “updated/downloaded” Installation and Driver Files from; "C:\Program Files\HP\HP Printer Name” (i.e. "C:\Program Files\HP\HP Officejet 6500 E710a-f”) to another location such as "C:\Drivers\” for easier access.

## Errors

If you try to manually install the Drivers through the **Print Management** Console, or the **Device Manager**, you will encounter the following errors:

- Error when installing Drivers through **Print Management**: "*Unable to install , x64, Type3 - User Mode driver. This operation is not supported.*”

  - The Microsoft KB Article 3041911 (hxxps://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3041911) is **NOT** applicable to this issue.
- Error when installing Drivers through **Device Manager**: “This operation requires an interactive window station”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Assumptions

- That you know how to install Drivers through the **Device Manager** & **Print Management** Console (because it is not part of this guide).

## Solution

1. Browse to the following Directory:

   - "**C:\Windows\System32**"
2. Change the **Owner** and the **Security permissions** for the following Folders:

   - **DriverStore**

     1. Right-click the **DriverStore** Folder and select **Properties**.
        [image: DriverStore_Properties]
     2. Select the **Security** Tab at the top, and Click on the **Advanced** button.
        [image: DriverStore_Security_Properties]
     3. Click on the **Change** link.
        [image: DriverStore_Security_Properties_Advanced]
     4. Type ***administrators*** in the pop-up, and Click **OK**.
        [image: DriverStore_Security_Properties_Owner]
     5. Check the “**Replace owner on subcontainers and objects**” box, and click **OK**.
        [image: DriverStore_Security_Properties_Replace_Owner]
     6. Click on the **Advanced** button AGAIN.
        [image: DriverStore_Security_Properties]
     7. Click on the **Change permissions** button.
        [image: DriverStore_Security_Advanced_Properties_Change_Permissions]
     8. Click on the **Add** button.
        [image: DriverStore_Security_Advanced_Properties_Add_Permissions]
     9. Click on the **Select a principal** link.
        [image: DriverStore_Security_Advanced_Properties_Add_Principal]
     10. Type ***administrators*** in the pop-up, and Click **OK**.
         [image: DriverStore_Security_Properties_Owner]
     11. Check the **Full control** box, and Click **OK**.
         [image: DriverStore_Security_Advanced_Properties_Add_Principal_Permissions]
     12. Check the **Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries from this object** and click **OK**.
         [image: DriverStore_Security_Advanced_Properties_Propagate_Permissions]
     13. Click **Yes** on the Windows Security pop-up.
         [image: Windows_Security_Warning]
     14. The **Security** Tab on the **DriverStore** Properties Window will “appear” to not have the newly added Permissions until they are reopened. Click **OK**.
         [image: DriverStore_Security_Permissions_OK]
         [image: DriverStore_Security_New_Permissions]
   - The Security permissions on the following Folders may also need to be changed **ONLY IF** changing the Security permissions on above Folder **DOES NOT** resolve the issue;

     - **drivers**
     - **DRVSTORE**
   - Update the missing HP Printer Drivers Through the **Device Manager** using the **HP Print and Scan Doctor** “updated/downloaded” Installation and Driver Files Folder Path Noted in the *Question* at the top of this page under *Symptoms*.

## References

You cannot install an additional 64-bit driver for a shared printer on a 32-bit print server
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3041911

"This operation requires an interactive window station” error
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/40ce7063-3d1e-4297-b682-35d8ef122634/this-operation-requires-an-interactive-window-station-error